# Delay Windows login screen waiting for some service statup

Tags: windows, wifi, windows-10, user-accounts

I want to wait for wifi connection before let user login to their laptop.
Can I be sure that the login screen is shown only after some service startup?

Comment: In an Active Directory domain environment? Or just standalone laptops?

Comment: I'm in an AD...